# Unity3D Project Configuration: Treat warnings as errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to configure my project from within the Unity Editor to treat all warning messages as errors, but I can't seem to find any documentation pertaining to this. Is there a way that I can configure this for my project? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a text file in `ProjectFolder/Assets/smcs.rsp`

Everything in that file will end up as compiler command-line parameters

The parameter to force warnings as errors is `-warnaserror+`, so add this to the `smcs.rsp`

If you are interested in other available parameters, run `UnityInstallFolder/editor/data/bin/smcs /?`

More on https://answers.unity.com/questions/216838/how-to-force-warnings-as-errors.html

Comment: Nothing special ;)

Comment: Also, according: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html
```Note that the .rsp file needs to match the compiler being invoked. For example:

when targeting the .NET 3.5 Equivalent (deprecated) scripting runtime version, mcs is used with mcs.rsp, and
when targeting the .NET 4.x Equivalent scripting runtime version compiler, csc is used with csc.rsp.```